# Controlling the determination of a spreadsheet's last row by getLastRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in my Google Sheet which copies a row of data from my "Job History" sheet to the "Job Schedule" sheet when cell AV in the row in "Job History" is cleared. This works fine if there are completely empty rows on the "Job Schedule" sheet, but some of the columns on the target sheet contain formulas and other characters, and this is causing `getLastRow()` to consider them as rows containing data.

How can I define what the last row is? Is there a way I can have `getLastRow()` check just one cell in the row to determine whether it is the last row or not? Here is my script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var editedCell;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Job History" && r.getColumn() == 47 && r.getValue() == "") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job Schedule");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var source = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    var notes = source.getNotes();
    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
    target.setNotes(notes);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Please see [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rB6Rzio34aqAdirBXXrtHZekcuIhUoM1yXjzJAa0f3E/edit#gid=842256017). The script it has was created to move rows from the "Job Schedule" sheet to the "Job History" sheet when it receives an `"X"` in its Column 47 cell, and to the "Job Holding" sheet when receiving an `"H"`. This has been working with no problems, but when I try to 'reverse' this move from the History and Holding sheets back to the Schedule sheet when their Column 47 values are cleared, it does not happen because some of the cells in the 'empty' rows are formatted with formulas and some characters, so if a row could be seen as empty if the cell in column B is empty, for example, then I think it would work.

Comment: You want to retrieve the row number of the last row of each column. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your reply - I would like to retrieve the row number of the last row of one specific column.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the specific column is constant, can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for asking whether you can ask about the constant column - yes you may.

Comment: @Tanaike What would you like to know? I'm still trying to get this to work, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I still cannot understand about the column you retrieve. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your private information. I think that it will help users think of your solution. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Your English is very good, I didn't even notice anything until you apologized for your skill. :) I added an example sheet to my original post, along a description of how it works. Thank you for your continued help!

Comment: Thank you for replying and the additional information. I would like to confirm it. Could you please give me a time?

Comment: @Tanaike Feel free to take a look when you are able to do so. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried to confirm to replicate the situation of your issue. Unfortunately, in my environment, but it couldn't be done. I'm really sorry. About ``I run into problems``, can I ask you about the detail?

Comment: @Tanaike I clarified the original post again, basically, it doesn't run in my setup because formulas aren't counted as 'blank'.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't alter the way in which `Sheet#getLastRow` operates, you can use it to limit your search space - i.e. instead of needing to check every row from the last possible (the row given by `getMaxRow()`) until you find a non-empty cell, you can step up from the `getLastRow()` row.

There are two approaches you can take - one simulates pressing `Ctrl` + `Up`, and the other tests the cells.

#### Simulated keypress / contiguous range detection

This uses the [`getNextDataCell`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction)) method, and then offsets once in the opposite direction (since it selects the next edge cell with data (or the edge of the sheet)). It will never return the first row in the sheet.

```
// Will throw if called on an expanding arrayformula column. Adds a new row if needed.
function getTargetRowInColumn_(sheet, columnIndex) {
  const maxRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
  // If the last row is the max row (e.g. an expanding arrayformula is present in a column),
  // then accessing getLastRow() + 1 will silently fail.
  var r = sheet.getRange(maxRow, columnIndex + 1);;
  if (sheet.getLastRow() === maxRow &&
     (r.getValue() !== "" || r.getFormula()))
  {
    // We want either the next row (which we will create), or there is a formula
    // that will add values to this column - user error for accessing this column.
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRow, 1);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    r = r.offset(1, 0);
    if (r.getValue() !== "" || r.getFormula())
      throw new RangeError("target column index '" + columnIndex + "' has expanding formula");
    
    return ++maxRow; // Same output as r.getRow(), but faster.
  }
  
  r = r.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);
  do {
    r = r.offset(1, 0);
  } while (r.getValue());
  return r.getRow();
}
```

edit: Since simple trigger calls don't display errors, you won't see a visual notification of any issues - you'll have to check your script's logs on Stackdriver. I've added some sanity checks for out-of-bounds `Range` accesses, which generally result in silent failures even when running in a context that allows displaying error messages.

#### Value testing

This uses a batch call to [`Range#getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) and [`Range#getFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas()), and then never uses the sheet again. Here we test if the array index is an empty string (`""`), and if it is, require that there is no formula in the index either. Both `getValues` and `getFormulas` return an empty string for "no value/formula", and since a formula may intentionally return the value `""`, both need to be checked.

```
// Does not throw if called on an expanding arrayformula column. Does not add a new row.
function getTargetRowInColumn_(sheet, columnIndex) {
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const r = sheet.getRange(1, columnIndex + 1, lastRow, 1);
  const values = r.getValues();
  const formulas = r.getFormulas();
  do {
    --lastRow;
  // isEmptyString = values[lastRow][0] === "";
  // isNotAFormula = !formulas[lastRow][0];
  //          isEmptyStringValue     &&     isNotAFormula
  } while (values[lastRow][0] === "" && !formulas[lastRow][0]);
  // lastRow now points to an array index that is occupied by either a formula or value.
  // += 1 converts from array index to Range row, and then += 1 again
  // (since we want the next row, which is empty).
  lastRow += 2;
  return lastRow;
}
```

The value testing approach will offer you the most flexibility, since you get to define exactly what controls the changes to the `lastRow` variable. However, since you define exactly what controls the changes to the `lastRow` variable, you have to consider possible pitfalls that are associated with comparison and short-circuit operators, and the data being stored on your sheet. The contiguous range detection removes all of this from your control, which is both good and bad (depending on your specific task). Note that both examples above use a column index, not a column. "A" is 0, "B" is 1, etc. If you want to change that, by all means, do so.

---

An example usage, which will pop up a toast containing the row number of the next blank cell in the first 3 columns of the first sheet in the spreadsheet whenever any cell on any sheet is edited.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const all = e.source.getSheets();
  var message;
  try {
    message = ["eh?", "bee", "see"].map(function (colName, i) {
      return [
        "Column '" + colName + "'",
        "(index " + i + "):",
        getTargetRowInColumn_(all[0], i)
      ].join(" ");
    }).join("; ");
  } catch (err) {
    message = err.message;
  }
  e.source.toast(message, "Row of the next blank cell in first sheet", 60);
  // Datestamp the next empty cell in column A of the first sheet.
  var targetColumn = 1; // Column A
  all[0].getRange(getTargetRowInColumn_(all[0], targetColumn - 1), targetColumn).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I've tried using both these methods but I must be doing something wrong. What is the correct way of adding this to my current script and making this run instead of getLastRow?

Comment: @J.Kubassek I've added an example that uses it, and fixed some issues with the first method

Comment: @tehhowh Sweet! Column 1 (B) is actually coming up correctly. So in my case then, how would I choose that entire row range? This isn't doing it: var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getTargetRowInColum_() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);

Comment: @J.Kubassek `getTargetRowInColumn_(...)` is not a method that belongs to the `Sheet` class, so you cannot call it like `targetsheet.getTargetRowInColumn_(...)`. When in doubt, keep it simple: `var targetRow = getTargetRowInColumn_(targetSheet, targetColumn - 1); targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, targetColumn, .... ` (with `targetColumn` being 1-based and the function assuming 0-based input)

Comment: @tehhowh Okay I'm getting closer now, but I don't understand how the targetColumn variable is supposed to replace my previous numColumns variable.

Comment: @J.Kubassek it doesn't. `targetColumn` is the 1-based column index for the start of the range in which you write the new data. `numColumns` is the width of the range in which you write the new data.

Comment: @tehhowh But then how is targetColumn defined? Thanks for your patience, by the way, this thing is giving me a headache.

Comment: @J.Kubassek you set it to whichever value it needs to be (1 for col A, 2 for col B, ... ). Its existence is for readability and maintainability - if you change the sheet column that you seek within for the next empty row, you only have to change the value assigned to `targetColumn`, rather than try to decipher which appearance of a number is actually the column reference and then change those.

Comment: @tehhowh Alright, I'll admit it, I'm lost. Is there any way you can take a look at my script at the link in the original post and help me out?